# Can I take a message using runtime.onMessage within a function that only executed when I click a button?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message

I'm brand new to js and making a chrome extension and I want to take a message from the background.js and use it in the popup.js after I click a button.

popup.js

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("BTC").addEventListener("click", bitcoin);
}
function bitcoin(){
  console.log("Clicked!");
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse){
    if(msg.greeting == "BTC"){
      var prices = msg.data;
      console.log(prices);
      sendResponse({});
      }
  });
}
```

background.js

```
function coinArray(coins){
      console.log(coins);
      for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++){
            var prices = new Array();
            prices[i] = coins[i].price_usd;
      }
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "BTC", data: prices}, function(response)  {});
}
```

I expect to see an array of the top 12 cryptocurrencies' prices from Coinmarketcap.com as an array in my popup console when I click the "BTC" button. I can console.log it in background.js no problem. The function coinArray is called when I load the data from the online API which is an XMLHTTPRequest not shown in the code.

Currently, only the "Clicked!" is coming through on the other end and I feel as if the problem might be that the onMessage line is within the function itself? Not sure where to go from here after looking up solutions to this problem. Any Clarity would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you take `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` outside of the function?

Comment: 1) the listener should be added at the start of the popup script. 
 2) the background page runs long before before the popup is shown if it's not "persistent": false in manifest.json, otherwise it won't run at all after being suspended once as there's nothing to wake it up, 3) it's not clear what the goal is here so maybe you don't need the background script. 4. Start using devtools debugger: each component of an extension has its own separate devtools window where you can set breakpoints, pause execution, inspect the variables and code flow.

Answer (score 1):

To frame your problem in intuitive terms: you're trying to make the background page "shout" first (whenever that `coinArray` function happens to run) but start listening for the "shout" later, after there's no sound anymore.

`sendMessage` is an active action, that should happen while `onMessage` is already (passively) listening, or it won't work ― it won't be "waiting" for you to start listening.

You need to reverse your logic here. Make the popup *request* the data from the background page with a `sendMessage`, which the background page can always listen to. You can then use `sendResponse` to deliver an answer to the popup.

1. Background registers an `onMessage` listener, waiting for the popup message.
2. User opens the popup and clicks the UI there.
3. Popup calls `sendMessage` for information.
4. Background receives the request, obtains the data needed (however that works in your case) and calls `sendResponse` with the data.
5. In the popup, the `sendMessage` callback is called with the data provided.

Of course, the exact implementation depends on how you retrieve the data. It's likely asynchronous, so don't forget to `return true` in the message listener so that `sendMessage()` can be called later. And in general, take a longer read of the [Messaging docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and [`chrome.runtime` docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime).